# How can I change the name and location of log4j.properties?

Tags: log4j

How can I change the name of `log4j.properties` and the location of this as well?

Comment: Hi @Idos, Thanks for help,Your answer is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change its location like so:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path_to_file_here/log4j.properties YourApplication
```

You should also [read the manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Regarding changing the name, this is how you can achieve this:
First, you must add the following line to your java runtime command:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=test.properties
```

For example lets assume you are using log4j in your web application deployed on Tomcat.
Add the above mentioned line in the java runtime command to start up Tomcat:

```
C:\Tools\java\j2sdk1.4.2_01\bin\java.exe -jar
-Duser.dir="C:\Tools\Tomcat 4.1"
-Dlog4j.configuration=test.properties
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Tools\Tomcat 4.1\common\endorsed"
"C:\Tools\Tomcat 4.1\bin\bootstrap.jar" start
```

You will also possibly want to read [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post, but the first thread when I searched for the question. And my found solution is:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "theNameIWant.properties");
```